# LaTeX produces an unacceptable intext citation call-out

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I tried to cite a paper with more than 4 authors. However, the latex cite it in an unacceptable way.

Here is my try:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\cite{ni}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} 
\bibliography{mybib2}
\end{document}
```

The article that I need to cite is:

```
@article{ni,
  title={Vine copula selection using mutual information for hydrological dependence modeling},
  author={Ni, Lingling and Wang, Dong and Wu, Jianfeng and Wang, Yuankun and Tao, Yuwei and Zhang, Jianyun and Liu, Jiufu and Xie,Fei},
  journal={Environmental research},
  volume={186},
  pages={109604},
  year={2020},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

I have got this: [image: the result]

Comment: `unsrtnat` needs \usepackage{natbib}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks a lot. I do not know how to thank you.

Comment: Observe that the issue you've encountered is *not* caused by the fact that the entry in question has more than 4 authors. Instead, it's caused by the failure to load the `natbib` citation management package.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out by @UlrikeFischer, the `unsrtnat` bibliography style -- as well as the `plainnat` and `abbrvnat` bib styles -- should be used with the [natbib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) citation management package.

All three of natbib's bibliography styles -- `plainnat`, `abbrvnat`, and `unsrtnat` -- are capable of producing numeric-style, superscript-style, and authoryear-style citation call-outs, depending on whether the `natbib` package is loaded with the options `numbers`, `super`, or `authoryear`, respectively.

For the `unsrtnat` bib style, though, only the options `numbers` and `super` make much sense. To be specific: loading `natbib` with the `authoryear` option does produce correctly-formatted authoryear-style citation call-outs when using the `unsrtnat` bib style; in the present case: "Ni et al. [2020]". The real issue is *finding* the "Ni et al." piece in a bibliography if the bib entries aren't sorted alphabetically. Hence, if you must create authoryear-style citation call-outs, don't use `unsrtnat`; instead (depending on your formatting requirements), use either `plainnat` or `abbrvnat` -- or some other suitable bib style. `natbib` is a very robust package and is known to work with lots and lots of bib styles in addition to `plainnat`, `abbrvnat`, and `unsrtnat`.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib2.bib}
@article{ni:2020,
  title={Vine copula selection using mutual information for hydrological dependence modeling},
  author={Ni, Lingling and Wang, Dong and Wu, Jianfeng and Wang, Yuankun and Tao, Yuwei and Zhang, Jianyun and Liu, Jiufu and Xie,Fei},
  journal={Environmental research},
  volume={186},
  pages={109604},
  year={2020},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\begin{document}
\cite{ni:2020}
\bibliography{mybib2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your great help. Really appreciated.